# multiple shared coonections via VPN and Debian server

Tags: debian, networking, connection-sharing

Please bear my ignorance, I'm learning a lot about networking and debian.

I want to use my Debian server (with multiple lan dongles) to share my vpn (nordvpn) connection to multiple clients in my home network. The ideal setup looks like this:

```
Wan router (internet access) dhcp server with ip 192.168.20.1
|
|-Debian eth0 with nordvpn. acting as DHCP server with ip 192.168.0.1
.....|
.....|-Router1 on eth1 of debian acting as bridge 192.168.0.2
...........|-Client1 of Router1 with ip 192.168.0.3
...........|-Client2 of Router1 with ip 192.168.0.5
.....|-Router2 on eth2 of debian acting as bridge ip 192.168.0.6
...........|-Client3 of Router2 with ip 192.168.0.7
...........|-Client4 of Router2 with ip 192.168.0.8
.....|-Router3 on eth3 of debian acting as bridge ip 192.168.0.9
.....|-Router4 on eth4 of debian acting as bridge ip 192.168.0.10
```

You can see the pattern emerging.

I'm currently able to set up the Routers with working internet using shared connection in the debian server but I need to be able for Client1 to see and ping Client3 and other on my network. The problem is that when sharing connection the server assigns different subnets to each interface (eth1=192.168.10.1, eth2=192.168.20.1 etc).

Ive tried bridging the interfaces and sharing connection to the br0 but no success connecting it to internet, Ive also tried bonding the interfaces without success and my last intent was with DnsMasq and routing but I'm a bit lost at the moment.

So, why Im doing this? I want a machine that is able to share the vpn but also run a plex server, adblocker, samba server and Homebridge for my home, I was able to set up all and the only problem Ive run into is the clients don't see each other.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Why is your router on 192.168.0.x but your Debian box trying to talk to it on 192.168.20.x? That won't work. 2. Also, your router presumably does DHCP service already so you don't want DHCP service on the same LAN connection from your Debian box. 3. You can't (shouldn't) use the same 192.168.0.x subnet for eth0 and bridge1 and bridge2 and... unless they are all the same LAN.

Comment: I think it would help if you could explain what you're trying to achieve (you've started to do that), and which server offers what service and from where. It seems that what you want is the Debian box to MASQUERADE your internal LAN to the router's LAN, but have port forwarding from the router's LAN through the Debian box into specific services on specific servers on the internal LAN

Comment: Thanks for the responses! My end goal is to be able to share my nordvpn with all the clients, after that the services can be setup in the subnet without problems.

What I'm currently facing is that when sharing the connection on EthN each get a different IP from the debian server (eth1 gets 10.4.0.1, eth2 gets 10.4.1.1 etc) so the clients that are behind the router1 through eth1 (apple extreme acting as a network switch) cant talk to clients on router2 through eth2 (network switch).

To do that the debian server should assign only one ip to all eth ports and there's where i'm facing trouble